# Can't comment on Android app

Tags: support, bug, comments, android-app

A few hours ago I installed the Stack Exchange app to ask a question over at [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/).

When I recieve an answer, I open the app to comment and the app gives me this notification:

`You have not joined this site yet, would you like to join?`

`Cancel` `Join Now`

When I tap `Join Now`, it does nothing but give me the following error on the status bar: `You are already a member on this site.`

I've been using Google Chrome since. Please help or fix, Chrome is aggravating me.